# Proper use of React getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: reactjs

In this example

https://codepen.io/ismail-codar/pen/QrXJgE?editors=1011

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    console.log("nextProps", nextProps, "\nprevState", prevState)
    if(nextProps.count !== prevState.count)
      return {count: nextProps.count};
    else
      return null;
  }
  handleIncrease(e) {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
  }
  handleDecrease(e) {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count - 1})
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.handleIncrease.bind(this)}>+</button>
      {this.state.count}
      <button onClick={this.handleDecrease.bind(this)}>-</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { initialCount: 1 };
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({initialCount: e.target.value})
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Counter count={this.state.initialCount} />
      <hr/>
      Change initial:<input type="number" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.initialCount} />
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Main/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Expected:
Clicking + / - buttons and textbox change must be update count

Currently: 
Main component stores initialCount in own state and passes initial count to child Counter Component.

If handleChange triggered from textbox and initialCount is updated also child Counter component is updated correctly because getDerivedStateFromProps static method provides this.

But changing count value in Counter component with updating local state via handleIncrease and handleDecrease methods it prolematic.

Problem is getDerivedStateFromProps re-trigger this time and resets count value. But I did not expect this because Counter component local state updating parent Main component is not updating. UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps is working this way.

Summary my getDerivedStateFromProps usage is incorrect or there is another solution for my scenario.

This version https://codepen.io/ismail-codar/pen/gzVZqm?editors=1011 is good with componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Trying to "sync" state to props like you do is extremely error-prone and leads to buggy applications.

In fact even your [example with `componentWillReceiveProps`](https://codepen.io/ismail-codar/pen/gzVZqm?editors=1111) has a bug in it.
If you re-render the parent component more often, you will lose user input.

Here is a [demo of the bug](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxgXgK?editors=1011#anon-login).
Increment counter, then click “demonstrate bug” and it will blow away the counter. But that button’s `setState` should have been completely unrelated.

This shows **why trying to sync state to props is a bad idea and should be avoided**.

Instead, try one of the following approaches:

1. You can make your component fully "controlled" by parent props and remove the local state.
2. Or, you can make your component fully “uncontrolled”, and reset the child state from the parent when necessary by giving the child a different `key`.

Both of these approaches are described in **[this article on the React blog about avoiding deriving state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html)**. The blog post includes detailed examples with demos so I strongly recommend to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but if you want to use the prop as a "seed" for the initial value to do it in the constructor and you don't even need `getDerivedStateFromProps`. You actually don't need to duplicate state:

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <button onClick={this.props.handleIncrease}>+</button>
      {this.props.count}
      <button onClick={this.props.handleDecrease}>-</button>
    </div>;
  }
}

class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 1 };
  }
  handleIncrease() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count + 1}))  
  }
  handleDecrease() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({count: prevState.count - 1}))  
  }
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
      <Counter count={this.state.count} />
      <hr/>
      Change initial: 
      <input 
        type="number" 
        handleIncrease={this.handleIncrease.bind(this)} 
        handleDecrease={this.handleDecrease.bind(this)} 
        count={this.state.count} 
      />
     </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Your suggestion is an alternate solution but I can't use it in realworld. A component must be update own state with own event handlers.